# Why can't Eclipse access iterparse from lxml.etree?

Tags: python, lxml, pydev, iterparse

I'm running PyDev in Eclipse.  After installing lxml with pip3, eclipse says it can't find the function iterparse from lxml.etree.  (But it can find lxml.etree just fine)

I've checked with `pip3 list` and lxml is listed, still it gives me an error on the line:

`from lxml.etree import iterparse` saying `Unresolved import: iterparse`

Does anyone know what's going on or how to diagnose this or fix?  Is it version-related?  (Edit: lmxl v5.1.0 installed with pip3 v23.3.2)

Comment: How can someone reply whether it's version related unless you give some version numbers?

Comment: Good point, but I was more wondering if it *could* be a version issue.  I'm using lxml 5.1.0, installed with pip3 (v23.3.2).  Are there any other version numbers that would be useful?